# How do I get a console menu to repeat once I have carried out one function so that I can carry out another without the program closing?

Tags: java, menu, console, repeat

I have set up a console menu like so:

```
int userOption = printMenu(sc);
while(userOption != 6){
switch(userOption) {
case 1: //function 1
        break;
case 2: //function 2
        break;
case 3: //function 3
        break;
case 4: //function 4
        break;
case 5: //function 5
        break;
case 6: //
        break
default: //statement asking for valid option
  }
}
```

However when I run this, it only allows me to carry out the method I want to properly once and then rather than return to my menu and allow me to continue using other functions on top of the one I have just used, it just keeps repeating the original function I used.

Can anybody help me out and give me some advice?

Comment: i´d blindly guess that you don´t get another userinput after you executed it once.

Comment: I do get asked for another user input however no matter what I enter it will just do the original function used. So for example if I select function 1 and complete it it will then ask me to choose another option but regardless of what number I input it will just carry out function 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what is given here you seem to not get another userinput. To solve it you need to get another userinput after executing the loop.

```
int userOption = printMenu(sc);
while(userOption != 6) {
    switch(userOption) {
        case 1: //function 1
                break;
        case 2: //function 2
                break;
        case 3: //function 3
                break;
        case 4: //function 4
                break;
        case 5: //function 5
                break;
        case 6: //
                break
        default: //statement asking for valid option
    }
    userOption = printMenu(sc);
};
```

As a little additon:
To save yourself the double input you could simply rewrite the loop to a do while loop:

```
int userOption = 0;
do {
    userOption = printMenu(sc);
    switch(userOption) {
        case 1: //function 1
                break;
        case 2: //function 2
                break;
        case 3: //function 3
                break;
        case 4: //function 4
                break;
        case 5: //function 5
                break;
        case 6: //
                break
        default: //statement asking for valid option
    }
} while(userOption != 6);
```

adding to your comment, you might not store the value into userOption again, but just ask for the input.

Comment: That's fixed it now by using the do while loop, thank you. I see now that I was asking for the input but because it wasn't looping it properly it wasn't storing it.

Comment: @espexplorer117 if this answer was useful to solve your problem, mark it as answer to help future users ...